# Create a wordpress Cron in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, cron, wget, wordpress

I use this cron job in Linux cpanel

```
*/5 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null "https://myurl.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=place_tags" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I migrated to google with cloud Ubuntu 20.04 I would like to set up the same cron job in Ubuntu using `crontab -e`

How do I have to write cron line to make it work? thanks!

Comment: you can just use as is in crontab -e I believe - what error do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

You are most of the way there. You'll need to do this:

1. SSH into your server
2. Type: `sudo crontab -e`
3. Add the following line:

   ```
   */5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q "https://myurl.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=place_tags" -O /dev/null
   ```
4. Save and exit: <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>

Be sure to use `sudo`, otherwise the cron job will only run when you're signed in with SSH.

Comment: with which user this crontab to be created?